# Eclipse Java EE and Tomcat 6: Error 404 requested resource not available

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I m getting the error

```
 HTTP Status 404 - /ot/LoginValidationServlet

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /ot/LoginValidationServlet

description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
```

whenever i run the following given code, I am using oracle 11g as my database where a table login contains the entry ('admin','admin'). When i enter the value in the form, the error shows. Also, my console is not showing any output even though i hav printed some comments.

I want that if i enter 'admin','admin' in the form of homepagge.jsp, the IndexAdmin.jsp page should open.

My coding is given below

Plsss help, i m new to j2ee and html

Pls reply as soon as possible

Homepage.jsp

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
        <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
         <title>Test Turf Corporation</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
       <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
            <script>
             function validateFunction()
     {
  var username=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
var password=document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
if (username==null || username=="" && password==null || password=="")
  {
     document.getElementById("error_username").innerHTML = "Enter Username and Password";
     return false;
  }
 if (username==null || username=="")
  {
     document.getElementById("error_username").innerHTML = "no name";
  return false;
  }
if (password==null || password=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("error_username").innerHTML = "Enter Password";
  return false;
  }
  return true;
      }
         </script>

      </head>
       <body id="top">
      <div class="wrapper col1">
     <div id="head" style="height:150px;">
      <h1><a href="#">TestTurf</a></h1>
       <p>Online Test Website</p>
       <div class="login" style="width:45%;float:right; margin-top: 1%; margin-bottom: 5%;margin-right:0;margin-left:70%; height:200px;">
           <form id="login" action="/ot/LoginValidationServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return validateFunction();">

          <table border="0" style="border: none;">
           <tr>
            <td style="border: none;">Username</td>
           <td style="border: none;">Password</td><td style="border: none;"></td>
             </tr>
            <tr><td style="border: none;"><input name="username" id="username" type="text"/></td>
             <td style="border: none;"><input name="password" id="password" type="password"></input></td><td style="border: none;">
             <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" class="submit" title="SUBMIT" style="background-color:#3D73B1; color:white; width:80px; height: 25px; border: none;"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td style="border: none;">Not a User?<a href="login.html" style="color:yellow;">Register Here</a></td><td style="border: none;">
                 <a href="" style="color:yellow;">Forgot Password</a></td></tr>
                </table></form>


         </div>

         <div id="topnav" style="margin-top: 4.25%;">
              <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="homepage.jsp">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Syllabus</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="Subject1.jsp">ADA</a></li>
               <li><a href="TOC.jsp">TOC</a></li>
              <li><a href="CSA.jsp">CSA</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

        <li class="last"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
           </ul>
             </div>

            </div>
               </div>
           <div class="wrapper col2">
              <div id="gallery">
              <ul>
                  <li class="placeholder" style="background-image:url(images/demo/m.jpg);">Image Holder</li>
             <li><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b1.gif);" href="#gallery">  <strong>Services</strong><span><img src="images/demo/m1.jpg" alt="" /> </span>       </a></li>
       <li><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b2.gif);" href="#gallery"><strong>Products</strong><span><img src="images/demo/hd3.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
          <li class="last"><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b3.gif);" href="#gallery"><strong>Company</strong><span><img src="images/demo/images.jpg" alt="" />    </span></a></li>
           </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="wrapper col5">
         <div id="footer">

            <!-- End Contact Form -->

           <!-- End Company Details -->
             <div id="copyright">
                 <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2014 - All Rights Reserved - <a href="#">Test Turf</a></p>
      <br class="clear" />
      </div>
           <div class="clear"></div>
          </div>
             </div>
          </body>
             </html>
```

My servlet

```
 LoginValidationServlet.java

        package onlinetest;

       import java.io.IOException;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
       import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

         /**
            * Servlet implementation class LoginValidationServlet
               */
          public class LoginValidationServlet extends HttpServlet {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               /**
                 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
               */
               public LoginValidationServlet() {
                super();
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

              /**
             * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               */
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          }

           /**
            * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
             */
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.print("Servlet 2");
    LoginService oLoginService = new LoginService();
    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.print("Servlet 1");

    long result=oLoginService.loginService(username,password);

    if(result==1){
        HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
        System.out.print("Servlet 2");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("IndexAdmin.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    else
    {
        System.out.print("Servlet");
        //response.sendRedirect("LoginError.jsp");
    }
        }

              }




                      LoginService.java

                   package onlinetest;
                  mport java.io.IOException;

                public class LoginService {

            public long loginService(String username,String password) throws IOException             {
                       long role=1;
                        System.out.print("Service class 1");
        //loginDAO ologinDAO=new loginDAO();
        // role=ologinDAO.validateLoginDetails(username,password);
        System.out.print("Service class");
        return role;
            }
                 }




                            loginDAO.java

                   package onlinetest;

                 import java.io.IOException;
                import java.sql.Connection;
                  import java.sql.DriverManager;
            import java.sql.ResultSet;
                import java.sql.SQLException;
             import java.sql.Statement;

              public class loginDAO {
                  @SuppressWarnings("finally")
               public long validateLoginDetails(String username, String password) throws IOException {  

                Connection con = null;
             Statement stmt = null;
                  ResultSet rs = null;
                      long role = 0;
                       String query = "select username,password,role from login where username like '"+ username + "' and password like '" + password + "'";

             String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:ot/bhumika@BHUMIKA:1521:XE";

       try {

        //String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.43.31:1521:XE";

        System.out.println("Query 1 executed");

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Query 2 executed");
         // con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"employee","bhumika");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Query 3 executed");
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println("Query 4executed");

        if (rs.next()) {
            role = rs.getLong("role");
            }
        return role;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print("DAO class not connected");
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(rs != null)
            rs.close();
            if(stmt != null)
            stmt.close();
            if(con !=null)
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print("DAO class not connected");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return role;

            }

               }

                  }





            login.java

            package onlinetest;

          public class login {
           String username;
             String password;
             long role;

            public String getUsername() {
    return username;
             }
              public String getPassword() {
            return password;
              }
                 public long getRole() {
        return role;
         }

            }



             IndexAdmin.jsp

               <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lang="EN" dir="ltr">
              <head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <title>Test Turf Corporation</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
        </head>
              <body id="top">
             <div class="wrapper col1">
                <div id="head">
                 <h1><a href="#">TestTurf</a></h1>
                 <p>Online Test Website</p>
                  <div id="topnav">
                   <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="homepage.jsp">Home</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Syllabus</a>
                     <ul>
         <li><a href="Subject1.jsp">ADA</a></li>
        <li><a href="TOC.jsp">TOC</a></li>
        <li><a href="CSA.jsp">CSA</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li>
            <li><a href="#">Add Questions</a></li>
           <li><a href="full-width.html">Test</a>
         <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Create Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete Test</a></li>
      </ul>
             </li>
           <li class="last"><a href="#">Results</a></li>

              </ul>
           </div>
            <div id="search">
            <h4 style="text-align: right;">

                Welcome <%=session.getAttribute("username") %> &nbsp; <a href="#">Logout</a>
                 </h4>   

                </div> 
             </div>
              </div>
           div class="wrapper col2">
              <div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                   <li class="placeholder" style="background-image:url(images/demo/m.jpg);">Image Holder</li>
         <li><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b1.gif);" href="#gallery"><strong>Services</strong><span><img src="images/demo/m1.jpg" alt="" /></span>        </a></li>
            <li><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b2.gif);" href="#gallery"><strong>Products</strong><span><img src="images/demo/hd3.jpg" alt="" /></span>           </a></li>
          <li class="last"><a class="swap" style="background-image:url(images/demo/b3.gif);" href="#gallery">           <strong>Company</strong><span><img src="images/demo/images.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
           </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
         </div>
         </div>

           <div class="wrapper col5">
           <div id="footer">

           <!-- End Contact Form -->

         <!-- End Company Details -->
              <div id="copyright">
              <p class="fl_left">Copyright &copy; 2014 - All Rights Reserved - <a href="#">Test Turf</a></p>
                <br class="clear" />
               </div>
           <div class="clear"></div>
               </div>
      </div>
          </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: are u using annontations or web.xml?

Comment: also plz seperate all your codes..format it properly...i have done one for u

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the application server (Tomcat) cannot find the path to /ot/LoginValidationServlet. It looks like you are using a standalone JEE/Tomcat solution so you might want to take a look at your servlet mappings to LoginValidationServlet in your web.xml file. Something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginValidationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginValidationServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Refer to [this article](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the servlet-mapping.

If you set the "url-pattern" as "/",
it means that your servlet will handle all of the incoming URL, which means, u can't get access to your files in the .war file, for example like images.

Try to modify it so.